# What are the extra objects returned from Node.getChildNodes()?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using the function `Node.getChildNodes();` to create a NodeList of the elements I need to use. This is the line of code:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("mealsaves").item(0).getChildNodes();
```

When I print name of the first object it prints "#text" and when I print the text content it prints a couple empty lines. It seems every other object in the list does this.

Can somebody tell me what this object is/what I can do with it?

EDIT: For example, when I print out the results of the array using this:

```
for (int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
    System.out.println(nList.item(i).getNodeName() + " - " + nList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

it prints this:

```
#text - 

ms1 - 
                obj1
                obj2
                obj3
                obj4
                obj5
                obj6
                obj7      

#text -   

ms2 - 
                obj1
                obj2
                obj3
                obj4
                obj5
                obj6
                obj7

#text -
```

EDIT 2: XML code

```
<saves>
    <diet>
        <mealsaves>
            <ms1>
                <name>obj1</name>
                <serving>obj2</serving>
                <calories>obj3</calories>
                <fat>obj4</fat>
                <carbs>obj5</carbs>
                <protein>obj6</protein>
                <mealtype>obj7</mealtype>         
            </ms1>  
            <ms2>
                <name>obj1</name>
                <serving>obj2</serving>
                <calories>obj3</calories>
                <fat>obj4</fat>
                <carbs>obj5</carbs>
                <protein>obj6</protein>
                <mealtype>obj7</mealtype>         
            </ms2>  
        </mealsaves>
    </diet>
<saves>
```

Comment: Please add some context. Show us the relevant XML. Show us how you print it. Show us what you expect to be printed, why you expect that and how it actually gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what it says - it's a text node. The text within and around elements is represented as text nodes. And sometimes a text node contains just whitespace. This might be due to extra space at the end of a line or indentation, for example.

It's good to remember that depending on the parser and platform some whitespace might be deemed "insignificant" and left out of the parsed tree.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. So when I do .getTextContent() on one of these, when might something besides empty lines be returned?

Comment: @alexanderd5398: Try doing it on an element that has some visible text content (like `<foo>hi there</foo>`)

Comment: All the elements that I got from that command had visible text content. It still returned empty lines

Comment: @alexanderd5398: But was it formatted (indented)? That adds empty space everywhere.

Comment: I don't think so. I added an example of what it prints. I've set it to indented in different methods, but I'm currently only running this one.

Comment: You need to paste the source XML document as well.

Comment: Added it, but I'm pretty sure I get it. The source code is indented  so that is what is added between each node?

Comment: As I said a couple of times already, yes. The linefeeds and indentation are showing up as text nodes.

Comment: Sorry lol, I thought you meant did I use the command to format it.